# How to Alphabetize the Names of All Online Players in minecraft spigot plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I want to alphabetize the names of all online players. and then get 1 random player from that

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()` to get all the online players.

Then you can use the `sort()` function to sort them and then use the `Random` class to get a casual player from the list.

Example:

```java
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class YourPluginClass {

    public void selectRandomPlayer() {
        // Step 1: Get the online players
        Player[] onlinePlayers = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().toArray(new Player[0]);

        // Step 2: Alphabetize the player names
        Arrays.sort(onlinePlayers, Comparator.comparing(Player::getName));

        // Step 3: Select a random player
        if (onlinePlayers.length > 0) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(onlinePlayers.length);
            Player randomPlayer = onlinePlayers[randomIndex];
        } else {
            // No players online
        }
    }
}
```